# How do I start my MYSQL database with Node & Express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, express

I'm currently using MYSQL, NODE & EXPRESS to build my first project using MYSQL, and I'm getting the following issue:

```
server started on port 3000
node_sql/index.js:16
    throw err;
    ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1128:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/hvaandres/Desktop/Cofffee/Coding_Projects/node_sql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/hvaandres/Desktop/Cofffee/Coding_Projects/node_sql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/hvaandres/Desktop/Cofffee/Coding_Projects/node_sql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hvaandres/Desktop/Cofffee/Coding_Projects/node_sql/index.js:14:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

My Index.js looks like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");

// Create my connection

const database = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
});

// Connect Database to node

database.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
    console.log("Something went wrong");
  }
  console.log("Our SQL is connected successfully");
});

const app = express();

// Create our DataBase

app.get("/createdb", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "CREATE DATABASE  little";
  database.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send("Database has been created...");
  });
});

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

What should I do to resolve this issue? This is my first MySQL project and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Could you please give me some feedback?

Comment: Did you have a running MySQL database server localhost?